# Align text in a JTable cell while maintaining JTable default renderer?

Tags: java, jtable, renderer

I have a JTable that does lovely alternations in coloration thanks to this code:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new BorderRenderer(new ColorRenderer(table
                .getDefaultRenderer(Object.class), colorProvider)));
```

(Here the "colorProvider" contains code that turns every other row light grey.) I have one column in which I would like to align text to center. If I simply set a DefaultCellRenderer on that column with center horizontal alignment, it overrides the table's default renderer and I lose my lovely stripes.

Can I keep the stripes and still change the alignment of a column?

To further complicate things, I have the above code in a super class. It is my sub classes that know what column(s) they would like to change the alignment on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks both to afk and camickr who led me to my final decision to write a TableCellRendererWrapper:

```
public class ColumnAlignmentRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer mWrappedRenderer;
    private int mDefaultAlignment = SwingConstants.LEFT;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpecialColumnAlignmentMap = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

    public ColumnAlignmentRenderer(TableCellRenderer pWrappedRenderer) {
        mWrappedRenderer = pWrappedRenderer;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable pTable, Object pValue, boolean pIsSelected,
            boolean pHasFocus, int pRow, int pColumn) {

        // Use the wrapped renderer
        Component renderedComponent = mWrappedRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(pTable, pValue, pIsSelected, pHasFocus,
                pRow, pColumn);

        // Set the alignment
        Integer alignment = mSpecialColumnAlignmentMap.get(pColumn);
        if (alignment != null) {
            ((JLabel)renderedComponent).setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
        } else {
            ((JLabel)renderedComponent).setHorizontalAlignment(mDefaultAlignment);
        }

        return renderedComponent;
    }

    public void setSpecialColumnAlignment(Integer pColumn, Integer pAlignment) {
        mSpecialColumnAlignmentMap.put(pColumn, pAlignment);
    }

    public void setDefaultAlignment(int pAlignment) {
        mDefaultAlignment = pAlignment;
    }
}
```

It's not perfect, but it gets the job done for me. To use it I do this:

```
        // Center alignment for "selected" column
        ColumnAlignmentRenderer cellRenderer = new ColumnAlignmentRenderer(getTable().getDefaultRenderer(Object.class));
        cellRenderer.setSpecialColumnAlignment(MyTableModel.COL_TO_CENTER, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        getTable().setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, cellRenderer);

        // Center alignmet for "selected" column header
        ColumnAlignmentRenderer headerRenderer = new ColumnAlignmentRenderer(getTable().getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer());
        headerRenderer.setSpecialColumnAlignment(MyTableModel.COL_TO_CENTER, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        getTable().getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(headerRenderer);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can I keep the stripes and still change the alignment of a column?

An easier approach is to use [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/). Then you can customize the alignment of individual renderers without affecting the row colors.

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(???).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to set the alignment on the default renederer that is set in your superclass's code, you will affect every cell.  An option you have is to create a new subclass for either `BorderRenderer` or `ColorRenderer`  (whichever is most appropriate), and in its `getTableCellRendererComponent` get the value returned from calling `super.getTableCellRendererComponent` and set the alignment on that before returning.  You can then set that an instance of that renderer for the column that you need aligned.

Answer (score 1):

use this method, it will align both header and table content to centered alignment. However you can change the CENTER to LEFT or RIGHT alignment.

```
    public void setTableAlignment(JTable table){
    // table header alignment
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    header.setDefaultRenderer(renderer);
    renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

   // table content alignment
   DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
   centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
   int rowNumber = table.getColumnCount();
   for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++){
   table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );
   }
   }
```